# How I can iterate a specific column?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet where on column A I have integer values.
I don't know how many values I have.
I don't know if there are space between every values.
There are values that have duplicates.

```
    A
--------
1| 76
2| 56
3| 34
4| ----
5| 9
6| 9
.| ---
.| ---
.| 56
```

I need to write on a file .txt all the values that don't have duplicates.

How I can code in VBA?

Comment: Do you want just non duplicated values? So only 9 would be listed. Or do you want all values with duplicates listed only once?

Comment: Do the rows you have listed with --- represent blank cells or non numeric values?

Comment: Please add to your question a desirable .txt output for the given example sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you there.

In you VBA IDE go to the tools menu and selecte references. Select "Microstoft ActiveX data objects 2.8 Library" for the ADODB recordset.

In you VBA IDE go to the tools menu and selecte references.  Select "Microsoft scripting runtime" for your file output.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Dim fs As FileSystemObject

    'Create the text file to write to
    Set fs = New FileSystemObject
    Set ts = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\test.txt", True, False)

    'Add fields to your recordset for storing data.
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "Value", adChar, 25
        .Open
    End With

    'This is getting the last used row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop through the rows
    lRow = 1
    Do While lRow <= lastRow

        'Check if this is already data that we are counting
        rs.Filter = ""
        rs.Filter = "Value='" & ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value & "'"

        If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
            'If this is a new value, add a new row for it
            rs.AddNew
            rs.Fields("Value").Value = ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value
            rs.Fields("Count").Value = 1
            rs.Update
        End If

    lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop

    'Remove the filer and move to the first record in the rs
    rs.Filter = ""
    rs.MoveFirst

    'Loop through the data we found and write it out
    Do While rs.EOF = False
        ts.WriteLine ws.Cells(rs.Fields("Value").Value)
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    'Clean up
    ts.Close: Set ts = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which uses `Dictionary` to get distinct values, `Join()` to make result text, and `FileSystemObject` to save the text to a file:

```
Sub WriteDistinctToFile()

    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim varItem As Variant
    Dim arrDistinct() As Variant

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rngSource = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(1)) ' only used cells in first column
    End With
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .Item("") = "" ' add empty key to remove it later
        For Each varItem In rngSource.Value
            .Item(varItem) = "" ' add each cell value to unique keys
        Next
        .Remove "" ' remove empty value
        arrDistinct = .Keys() ' convert to array
    End With
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\Test.txt", 2, True, 0) ' open text file for output in ASCII
        .Write Join(arrDistinct, vbCrLf) ' join values from array into new line separated string, then write to file
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```